# Find mistake in logarithm calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I want to find the solution of $$2 \log_{10} u=2,$$ where $\log_{10}$ means the base $10$ logarithm.

So I got $2 \log_{10} u=2\Leftrightarrow\log_{10} u^2 =2\Leftrightarrow u^2=10^2 \Leftrightarrow u\in\{\pm 10\}$.

But this is wrong, so where is my mistake?

Comment: Logarithms are defined only for positive real numbers. Hence, $u = -10$ cannot be a solution. Only solution to your problem is $u = 10$.

Comment: You should have divided by $2$ at the outset.

Comment: @quasi That's an alternate solution, not an identification of a mistake. I do agree that that is a better way to get to the solution, though, being both easier and less error-prone.

Comment: @Arthur: Sure, but the mistake was already identified. My comment was to show that the OP's approach was not the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negative numbers have no logarithms. The only solution is $10$.